# Removing Rational Software Architect dependency for generating automated code

Tags: java, spring, docker, dependencies, rational-rsa

I am stuck up with a set of old project based on EJB 2.1 that are eventually combined into a EAR to be deployed on WAS 8.5.5. It is built using Rational Software Architect and so it has a tight coupling with the RSA’s way of generating automatic code for the entity beans. I am not yet aware if there are any other automatic generated components in the projects apart from the entity beans.

The project has been dockerized by using a WAS 8.5.5 base docker image. But while making changes to the code, I am required to use RSA to build the projects JARs due to the dependency on RSA for automatic generation of code. After the JARs are build, I use make command to, build the EAR and call docker-compose to build the docker image.

I want to get rid of the RSA dependency so I can use a single make command to get the build of the project and it’s docker image created. I use Mac and RSA does not work as expected on Mac and neither is WAS supported on Mac. So that is one more important reason to get this dependency removed.

I am looking for following answers :

> Is there a way to automate the creation of entity beans for EJB 2.1 using command line options (and remove RSA dependency) ?
>
> Eventually, I also want to migrate the project to either EJB 3.0/latest OR, better yet migrate to Spring. This should reduce the complexity and increase maintainability of the project. Is it good idea to migrate the project to EJB latest OR Spring (boot) ? Apart from maintainability, What are the other advantages I would get from such a migration ?

Comment: "...reduce the complexity and hence the maintainability of the project." -- is that worded correctly?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils : Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected that now.

Answer (score 0):

This response is likely far too late, but I managed to dockerise a legacy RSA project so that the build could be built without an RSA installation and by standard build tools on any platform. It is possible. It wont get rid of RSA, but it will give you some breathing space to consider your options.